# C# Encode a string with multiple types of characters to HTML

Tags: c#, html, winforms, encode

I have a doubt that I am not even sure what kind of doubt it is. I'll just explain it.

I need to convert a string, in C# Windows forms, that might have any kind of characters to HTML format. I need this to use an existing tool with my program, so it has to be exactly like this.

The problem is that the `HtmlEncode` function doesn't work as intended. I found a website that does EXACTLY what I need. That website is: http://web.forret.com/tools/html.asp .

In this website when I post the string:

```
"® € ì Ù Ω µ drokluží zlůd paněž  Ř  ř common text"
```

and convert it to html I get:

```
"&#174; &#8364; &#236; &#217; &amp;#937; &#181; droklu&#382;&#237; zl&amp;#367;d pan&amp;#283;&#382;  &amp;#344;  &amp;#345; common text"
```

and I need to obtain EXACTLY THE SAME in C#. Note that, when I ask the convertion, the original text changes to:

```
"® **€ ì Ù &#937; µ drokluží zl&#367;d pan&#283;ž  &#344;  &#345; common text**"
```

so I believe that a pre-conversion is done before the final conversion. I just can't find which.

Note that `HTMLEncode` produces

```
"&#174; € &#236; &#217; Ω &#181; drokluž&#237; zlůd paněž  Ř  ř common text"
```

which doesn't even convert some symbols like `€` `Ω` or the foreign text `zlůd paněž  Ř  ř**`.

I already lost a huge ammount of time in this, so any kind of help would be extremelly appreciated. I hope the question was clear enough.

Comment: @ASGM thanks, it looks much better indeed :)

Comment: You're welcome, but the real credit should go to @rivimey (I just modified their edits slightly), but I appear as the most recent editor because I approved their changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking following code:

```
public string HTMLEncodeSpecialChars(string text)
{
  System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
  foreach (char c in text){
    if(c>127) // chars not in ASCII
      sb.Append(String.Format("&#{0};",(int)c));
    else
      sb.Append(c);
  }
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't special case an input character of &, which it needs to.

Comment: It does work, althought the output code is not exactly the same as that website's. Thanks!! Just 2 questions. 1- What is, technically, this that the function was doing? Basically, what did I need? (because I just knew I needed that end result, I had no clue what I was looking at). 2 - Could you provide the reverse code?

Comment: @viper 1) It convert any char which is no in ASCII (so which code number is greater than 127) to HTML encoded equivalent. Normal C# function does it also but it decoded chars which are not in UTF-8.

Comment: @viper 2) For reverse code you could standard method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx

Comment: Just a thought: ISTR there is a System Char Types module which includes things like IsPrint(x): is character x printable? this would be a better test than Garath or I have given.

Comment: @Garath. I am sorry to insist, but can you explain again **what was I looking for** and **why your function gives me what I wanted better than the HtmlEncode** one?

Comment: You were looking for Html Encode function which will encode all chars which are not in ACSII lower table (look here: http://www.asciitable.com/) The chars like: ® € ì Ù Ω, has value (char is an integer) more than 127. Original HmtlEncode function knows that chars from 127 to 256 will render correctly on client side, so it does not convert them. I hope now it is clear.

Comment: @Garath it is, indeed, clear. Thank you very much! Marked as accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

If your input is in UTF, could you not just parse the text with a loop that does (pseudocode)

```
foreach char in string
    if char code greater than 126
        print "&#" + charcode + ";"
    else if char is &
        print "&amp;"
    else 
        print char
```

refinements possible...

It would be better to use the entity strings, IMO as they are clearer to human reader and less likely to be misinterpreted by computer. However, the above should work...

Comment: I will try it and get back to you

Comment: I do believe this would work but, as I was doing it, someone posted it with code! Thank you so much anyways.